# List the database privileges using psql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, permissions, psql

I'm in the middle of a database server migration and I can't figure (after googling and searching here) how can I list the database privileges (or all the privileges across the server) on PostgreSQL using the `psql` command line tool?

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 and my PostgreSQL version is 8.2.x.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

```
postgres=> \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

The [docs on Privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-priv.html#PRIVILEGE-ABBREVS-TABLE) give an explanation of how to interpret the output. For specific privileges on a table of the current database, use `\z myTable`.

Comment: `\z myTable` is perfect for ensuring that you've successfully granted access to someone and avoiding looking like an idiot when you say "okay does it work now? it **doesn't???**"

Answer (score 192):

You can do that by following:

```
SELECT grantee, privilege_type 
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
WHERE table_name='mytable'
```

This gives you this kind of output:

```
mail=# select grantee, privilege_type from information_schema.role_table_grants where table_name='aliases';
   grantee    |  privilege_type
--------------+-----------------
 mailreader   |  INSERT
 mailreader   |  SELECT
 mailreader   |  UPDATE
 mailreader   |  DELETE
 mailreader   |  TRUNCATE
 mailreader   |  REFERENCES
 mailreader   |  TRIGGER
(7 rows)

mail=#
```

Comment: Note that (as least under Postgres 9.4) the above will not work for materialized views.

Comment: Note that you may need to run these as postgres user, or else some grants may not appear (e.g. `\dp` tells you that a specific user has access to a table, but this select would not select the related grants).

Answer (score 182):

perhaps you mean listing users and their privileges for a database - I can't quite tell from the question:

```
postgres=> \du
                             List of roles
    Role name    |  Attributes  |                    Member of
-----------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------
 dba             | Create role  | {util_user,helpdesk_user,helpdesk_admin}
 helpdesk_admin  | Cannot login | {helpdesk_user}
 helpdesk_user   | Cannot login | {helpdesk_reader}
 jack            |              | {helpdesk_admin}
 postgres        | Superuser    | {}
                 : Create role
                 : Create DB
```

Comment: Nope I wanted a way to list the privileges of a specific database, but I already figured it out. Owner of the database always has all privileges, right? And afterwards we can add more privileges on the database to other users/groups. Those are listed with the \l command. But very thanks anyway.

Answer (score 44):

Using `psql` meta-commands:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Going over the page with Ctrl+F gives:

> `\ddp [ pattern ]`
>   Lists default access privilege settings.
>
> `\dp [ pattern ]` Lists tables, views and sequences with their
>   associated access privileges.
>
> `\l[+] [ pattern ]` List the databases in the server and show ....
>   access privileges.

Also mentioned above, but not found with word "privileges" on the manual page:

`\du+` for roles with login and `\dg+` for roles without - will have a filed `"Member of"` where you find roles granted to roles.

I deliberately skip function and language privileges here, found in `psql` manual as barely manipulated (and if you do use those privileges you wont come here for an advise). same for user defined types, domains and so on - using "+" after the meta-command will show you privileges if applicable.

---

A little extreme way to check the privileges is dropping the user in transaction, e.g.:

```
s=# begin; drop user x;
BEGIN
Time: 0.124 ms
ERROR:  role "x" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  privileges for type "SO dT"
privileges for sequence so
privileges for schema bin
privileges for table xx
privileges for table "csTest"
privileges for table tmp_x
privileges for table s1
privileges for table test
Time: 0.211 ms
s=# rollback;
ROLLBACK
Time: 0.150 ms
```

When the list is longer than N, (at least in 9.3), warning with list of privileges is collapsed, but you still can find it full in logs...

Comment: In v12 `\du+`and `\dg+`seems to return same results. I have 2 roles with `NOLOGIN`option and both are listed with both commands. Checked with `\?`and it gives same description for both commands so I guess the role-with-login vs user distinction is no longer available.

Answer (score 44):

Undercovers psql uses the bellow query when you issue `\du` command.

```
SELECT r.rolname, r.rolsuper, r.rolinherit,
  r.rolcreaterole, r.rolcreatedb, r.rolcanlogin,
  r.rolconnlimit, r.rolvaliduntil,
  ARRAY(SELECT b.rolname
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON (m.roleid = b.oid)
        WHERE m.member = r.oid) as memberof
, r.rolreplication
, r.rolbypassrls
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r
WHERE r.rolname !~ '^pg_'
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: `   "ERROR:  column r.rolbypassrls does not exist\n\nLINE 9:     , r.rolbypassrls\n\n              ^\n",` unfortunately does not work

Comment: source? whats the query for `\l`?

Answer (score 30):

This is how you can list all privileges of a role (grantee):

```
SELECT grantor, grantee, table_schema, table_name, privilege_type
FROM information_schema.table_privileges
WHERE grantee = 'myuser'
```

Will result in:

```
 grantor  | grantee  | table_schema | table_name | privilege_type
----------+----------+--------------+------------+----------------
 postgres | myuser   | myapp        | employees  | INSERT
 postgres | myuser   | myapp        | employees  | SELECT
 postgres | myuser   | myapp        | employees  | UPDATE
 postgres | myuser   | myapp        | employees  | DELETE
```

Works in PG 10

Comment: Works also in Pg 12.

Comment: I wrote `GRANT SELECT ON "MyView" TO user1;` and `GRANT UPDATE ("col1") ON "MyView" TO user1;` but `privilege_type` shows only `SELECT`. Why no `UPDATE`? Can I see column-specific update privileges?

Comment: Works also in Pg 15.

Answer (score 16):

This is my query composed of multiple answers on this question:

```sql
SELECT grantee AS user, CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) AS table, 
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(privilege_type) = 7 THEN 'ALL'
        ELSE ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(privilege_type), ', ')
    END AS grants
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants
GROUP BY table_name, table_schema, grantee;
```

This results in something like this:

```
+------+--------------+----------------+
| user |    table     |     grants     |
+------+--------------+----------------+
| foo  | schema.table | ALL            |
| bar  | schema.table | SELECT, INSERT |
+------+--------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Getting this error in pg 9.4 -                                                                          
     ERROR:  could not find array type for data type information_schema.character_data

Comment: gr8 job with aggregation.

Answer (score 14):

A (possibly obvious) additional step is become the postgres user, otherwise you may get errors about roles not existing.

```
sudo su - postgres
psql -l
```

or

```
psql
postgres=> \l
```

Answer (score 4):

You can input by following:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_roles;
```

and you will get

```
rolname | rolsuper | rolinherit | rolcreaterole | rolcreatedb | rolcanlogin | rolreplication | rolconnlimit | rolpassword | rolvaliduntil | rolbypassrls | rolconfig | oid
```

maybe here you will think that there are too many roles, and this time, you can use WHERE to select what role you want to see

```
SELECT * FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='your role name';
```

In fact, you can also just input

```
\du
```

and you will see all roles you created instead of default

Comment: How is this different from existing answers posted earlier?

Comment: Here as a supplement to the previous, I think, the previous answers were missing this part or not concise enough.

Answer (score 4):

list database owners

```sql
select d.datname, r.rolname
from pg_catalog.pg_database d, pg_catalog.pg_roles r
where d.datdba = r.oid;
```

docs: [pg_database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/catalog-pg-database.html) and [pg_roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/view-pg-roles.html)

related: test for a specific privilege:

```
select has_database_privilege('dbname', 'CREATE');
```

docs: [has_database_privilege](https://pgpedia.info/h/has_database_privilege.html) ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59859211/10440128))