# Find objects linked to a PostgreSQL role

Tags: postgresql, permissions

Some times ago I created a PostgreSQL user named **user1** (PostgreSQL 9.4.9).

I want to drop this user. So I first revoke all permissions on tables, sequences, functions, default privileges and ownership too:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public REVOKE ALL ON SEQUENCES FROM user1;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM user1;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTIONS FROM user1;

REVOKE ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public FROM user1;
REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM user1;
REVOKE ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public FROM user1;

REASSIGN OWNED BY user1 TO postgres;
```

However it seems that one object remains linked to this user in 2 databases:

```
postgres=# DROP ROLE user1;
ERROR:  role "user1" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  1 object in database db1
1 object in database db2
```

It even seems to be a function:

```
postgres=# \c db1
You are now connected to database "db1" as user "postgres".
db1=# DROP ROLE user1;
ERROR:  role "user1" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  privileges for function text(boolean)
1 object in database db2
```

But I can not determine which object is owned or related to user1.

If I `pg_dump -s db1 | grep user1` I get no result! Could it be a global object?

How can I identify the missing object?

I have executed the commands in each database (db1 and db2). I do not want to drop objects owned by `user1`, just want to reassign or remove grants for this user.

Comment: Related question that this does not seem to address, but would be useful to address as other posts link to this one:  When the Error is of the form: `Could not drop the role. ERROR: role "[username]" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it DETAIL: [#] objects in database [dbname]`.  How do you identify these objects prior to reassigning and/or dropping them?

Comment: ignore the above comment. i'm an idiot.  If you use the pgadmin4 GUI to right-click on a role and select delete/drop, you get only the above error message. But if you actually run the query `drop role [username]`, then you get the full report of all the privileges that are causing the error in the pgadmin Messages pane.  :facepalm:

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Answer to question asked

To look for the function in the error message and its owner:

```
SELECT oid::regprocedure AS function
     , pg_get_userbyid(proowner) AS owner
FROM   pg_proc
WHERE  oid = 'text(boolean)'::regprocedure;
```

Related:

- [DROP FUNCTION without knowing the number/type of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7623246/939860)

#### Actual problem

The error message says:

> DETAIL:  privileges for function text(boolean)

It's *not* about ownership but about ***privileges***.

[The manual for `DROP ROLE`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-droprole.html)

> Before dropping the role, you must drop all the objects it owns (or
>   reassign their ownership) **and revoke any privileges the role has been
>   granted on other objects**.

[And for `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)

> If you wish to drop a role for which the default privileges have been
>   altered, it is necessary to reverse the changes in its default
>   privileges or use `DROP OWNED` BY to **get rid of the default privileges
>   entry for the role**.

It also looks like you only executed `REASSIGN OWNED` in one DB, but [the manual instructs:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reassign-owned.html)

> Because `REASSIGN OWNED` does not affect objects within other
>   databases, it is usually necessary to **execute this command in each
>   database** that contains objects owned by a role that is to be removed.

Bold emphasis mine.

And you restricted your commands with `IN SCHEMA public`. Drop that clause to target the whole DB. But don't bother, there is a ...

### Simple solution with [`DROP OWNED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-drop-owned.html)

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY user1 TO postgres;
DROP OWNED BY user1;
```

All the role's objects changed ownership to `postgres` with the first command and are safe now. The wording of `DROP OWNED` is a bit misleading, since it also gets rid of all privileges and default privileges. [The manual for `DROP OWNED`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-drop-owned.html)

> `DROP OWNED` drops all the objects within the current database that are
>   owned by one of the specified roles. **Any privileges granted to the
>   given roles on objects in the current database and on shared objects
>   (databases, tablespaces) will also be revoked.**

Repeat in all relevant DBs, then you can move in for the kill:

```
DROP ROLE user1;
```

Comment: This finds nothing. Yet `DROP ROLE myuser` throws an error because there are still objects that the user owns...

Comment: @Cerin What is "this"? The `SELECT` query at the top, which only looks for routines (functions and procedures) matching the OP's problem. Or `REASSIGN OWNED` + `DROP OWNED` as suggested, which takes care of *all* objects and privileges in the current DB? (Has to be executed  in all DBs of the same DB cluster that may be involved.)

Comment: I want to link this answer. With help of that query can list objects access to which were granted to your role: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/285595/91706

Answer (score 15):

The query below lists objects with owners. For all privileges we actually need more.

```
--r = ordinary table, i = index, S = sequence, v = view, m = materialized view, c = composite type, t = TOAST table, f = foreign table
SELECT 
    n.nspname AS schema_name,
    c.relname AS rel_name,
    c.relkind AS rel_kind,
    pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) AS owner_name
  FROM pg_class c
  JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace

UNION ALL

-- functions (or procedures)
SELECT
    n.nspname AS schema_name,
    p.proname,
    'p',
    pg_get_userbyid(p.proowner)
  FROM pg_proc p
  JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
```

Comment: I still do not find the missing object with this.

Comment: @NicolasPayart: Are you executing the query in the right database?

Comment: The answer with more other approaches: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/4286/91706

Answer (score 2):

You need to first connect to the database.
In your instance that would be

```
\c db1
```

and

```
\c db2
```

Then try running the `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES` and `REASSIGN OWNED/DROP OWNED BY` statements again.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your first answer.  However, before posting, please think about what does this add to the existing answers, and describe this in your answer, too.

Answer (score -2):

DROP ROLE also depends on privileges of the ROLE - see DETAIL in the below:

## DROP USER alice;

ERROR:  role "alice" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  privileges for table bloat

## REVOKE UPDATE on bloat FROM alice;

REVOKE

## DROP USER alice;

DROP ROLE