# Remove persistent privileges on table

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to remove the role `my_schema-writers`. I can't because it owns objects:

```
ERROR:  role "my_schema-writers" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  privileges for table your_schema.your_table
1101 objects in database *******
1 object in database *******
1 object in database *******
1 object in database *******
1 object in database *******
```

Sure enough, it has privileges:

```
my_database=# \dp your_schema.your_table

                                                  Access privileges
┌─────────────┬───────────────────┬───────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────┐
│   Schema    │       Name        │ Type  │                  Access privileges                         │ Column privileges │
├─────────────┼───────────────────┼───────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ your_schema │     your_table    │ table │ "your_schema-writers"=arwdDxt/"your_schema-writers"       ↵│                   │
│             │                   │       │ "***-writers"=arwdDxt/"your_schema-writers"               ↵│                   │
│             │                   │       │ "server-superusers"=a*r*w*d*D*x*t*/"your_schema-writers"  ↵│                   │
│             │                   │       │ "server-writers"=arwdDxt/"server-superusers"              ↵│                   │
│             │                   │       │ =r/"server-superusers"                                    ↵│                   │
│             │                   │       │ "my_schema-writers"=rx/"server-superusers"                 │                   │
└─────────────┴───────────────────┴───────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

That is, role `my_schema-writers` has privileges on `your_schema.your_table`.

I can revoke all privileges:

```
my_database=# REVOKE ALL ON TABLE your_schema.your_table FROM "my_schema-writers";
Time: 1.884 ms
```

But the privileges persist:

```
my_database=# \dp your_schema.your_table

                                                  Access privileges
┌─────────────┬───────────────────┬───────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────┐
│   Schema    │       Name        │ Type  │                  Access privileges                         │ Column privileges │
├─────────────┼───────────────────┼───────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ your_schema │     your_table    │ table │ "your_schema-writers"=arwdDxt/"your_schema-writers"       ↵│                   │
│             │                   │       │ "***-writers"=arwdDxt/"your_schema-writers"               ↵│                   │
│             │                   │       │ "server-superusers"=a*r*w*d*D*x*t*/"your_schema-writers"  ↵│                   │
│             │                   │       │ "server-writers"=arwdDxt/"server-superusers"              ↵│                   │
│             │                   │       │ =r/"server-superusers"                                    ↵│                   │
│             │                   │       │ "my_schema-writers"=rx/"server-superusers"                 │                   │
└─────────────┴───────────────────┴───────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

And I still can't remove the role:

```
ERROR:  role "my_schema-writers" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  privileges for table your_schema.your_table
1101 objects in database *******
1 object in database *******
1 object in database *******
1 object in database *******
1 object in database *******
```

`my_schema-writers` is not a member any other role and has no member roles:

```
rpm_2016_02=# \du "my_schema-writers"
               List of roles
┌───────────────────┬──────────────┬───────────┐
│    Role name      │  Attributes  │ Member of │
├───────────────────┼──────────────┼───────────┤
│ my_schema-writers │ Cannot login │ {}        │
└───────────────────┴──────────────┴───────────┘
```

**How do I remove these privileges and the role?** I'm able to remove the `1101 objects` and the other 4 individual `1 object...` is the same table in backup databases.

I also tried `DROP OWNED BY "my_schema-writers";` with no error, but still not able to drop the role.

Answer (score 2):

> *I also tried `DROP OWNED BY "my_schema-writers";` ...*

[**`DROP OWNED`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-drop-owned.html) is the right tool. Plus, [`REASSIGN OWNED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reassign-owned.html) first if the role might *own* anything. But [the manual instructs:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-drop-owned.html)

> `DROP OWNED` is often used to prepare for the removal of one or more
>   roles. Because `DROP OWNED` only affects the objects in the current
>   database, it is usually necessary to **execute this command in each
>   database** that contains objects owned by a role that is to be removed.

Bold emphasis mine. So repeat this **in every involved database**:

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY "my_schema-writers" TO postgres;  -- or any target role of your choice
DROP OWNED BY "my_schema-writers";
```

Of course, you need privileges on source and target roles. Executing this as superuser avoids all "permission denied" errors.

Then try again:

```
DROP ROLE "my_schema-writers";
```

Closely related answer with more details:

- [Find objects linked to a PostgreSQL role](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155332/find-objects-linked-to-a-postgresql-role/155356#155356)

#### Why didn't `REVOKE ALL` work as expected?

You ran:

```
my_database=# REVOKE ALL ON TABLE your_schema.your_table FROM "my_schema-writers";
```

You haven't been too forthcoming, but the `#` in a psql prompt `my_database=#` would normally indicate a superuser as session user.

The manual:

> A user can only revoke privileges that were granted directly by that
>   user. If, for example, user A has granted a privilege with grant
>   option to user B, and user B has in turn granted it to user C, then
>   user A cannot revoke the privilege directly from C. Instead, user A
>   could revoke the grant option from user B and use the `CASCADE` option
>   so that the privilege is in turn revoked from user C. For another
>   example, if both A and B have granted the same privilege to C, A can
>   revoke their own grant but not B's grant, so C will still effectively
>   have the privilege.
>
> [...]
>
> If a superuser chooses to issue a `GRANT` or `REVOKE` command, the
>   command is performed as though it were issued by the owner of the
>   affected object. Since all privileges ultimately come from the object
>   owner (possibly indirectly via chains of grant options), it is
>   possible for a superuser to revoke all privileges, but this might
>   require use of `CASCADE` as stated above.

Privileges might have persisted this way. If so, repeating with `CASCADE` should remove them. But I wouldn't bother. `REASSIGN OWNED` / `DROP OWNED` is the way to go.

A table of the same name in another DB (like you mentioned in a comment) has no bearing on this for Postgres - as long as you are not logged into the wrong DB by mistake.

Aside:
[Postgres 9.2 is too old by now (reached EOL in 2017)](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Consider updating to a current version at your earliest opportunity. Don't expect it to have any part in this, but I am not sure. It's just too old.

Comment: I see that `REASSIGN/DROP OWNED` must be run in each database and it is true that my_schema.my_table exists in the other database, but does that explain why the privileges for `my_schema.my_table` in the current database aren't removed?

Comment: @DylanHettinger: I added a possible explanation above.

Comment: Interestingly, the `1 object in database...` is always `"my_schema-writers"=rx/"server-superusers"` on `your_schema.your_table`- the same privileges and same table. I am using a superuser role, namely `server-superusers`, the role used to give the grant the privileges. I think I'll recreate `your_schema.your_table` from scratch. Perhaps it is a bug in 9.2 and we're in the process of upgrading now.

Comment: I am out of ideas. Maybe something about pg 9.2 I don't remember. Or a corrupted system catalog. Thumbs up for the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

This : -   `\dp your_schema.your_table`

command shows my_schema-writers as all privileges like select,insert,update

Follow below things

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA your_schema FROM my_schema-writers;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA your_schema FROM my_schema-writers; --just incase if you have sequence 
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA your_schema FROM my_schema-writers; --just incase if you have functions 
DROP USER my_schema-writers;
```

If still unable to drop try `REASSIGN OWNED BY`

Comment: Thanks, I've run all of those as well to no avail

Comment: have u try reassign owned  command and then drop ?