# How to list all grants per user/role on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I've run these statements on Postgres CLI (I'm using PostgreSQL v13.1):

```
CREATE ROLE blog_user;
GRANT blog_user TO current_user;
```

And I created a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION SIGNUP(username TEXT, email TEXT, password TEXT)
RETURNS jwt_token AS
$$
DECLARE
  token_information jwt_token;
BEGIN
....
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Finally I granted a permission:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION SIGNUP(username TEXT, email TEXT, password TEXT) TO anonymous;
```

I wish to list all grants per user/role in my schema/database. `\du` and `\du+` show basic information, which does not contain info about the grant (*execute on function*) made recently.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While the following is not a complete solution (column privs aren't included, it doesn't have the function signatures) you should hopefully be able to get most of what you're asking for using:

```
SELECT rug.grantor,
        rug.grantee,
        rug.object_catalog,
        rug.object_schema,
        rug.object_name,
        rug.object_type,
        rug.privilege_type,
        rug.is_grantable,
        null::text AS with_hierarchy
    FROM information_schema.role_usage_grants rug
    WHERE rug.object_schema NOT IN ( 'pg_catalog', 'information_schema' )
        AND grantor <> grantee
UNION
SELECT rtg.grantor,
        rtg.grantee,
        rtg.table_catalog,
        rtg.table_schema,
        rtg.table_name,
        tab.table_type,
        rtg.privilege_type,
        rtg.is_grantable,
        rtg.with_hierarchy
    FROM information_schema.role_table_grants rtg
    LEFT JOIN information_schema.tables tab
        ON ( tab.table_catalog = rtg.table_catalog
            AND tab.table_schema = rtg.table_schema
            AND tab.table_name = rtg.table_name )
    WHERE rtg.table_schema NOT IN ( 'pg_catalog', 'information_schema' )
        AND grantor <> grantee
UNION
SELECT rrg.grantor,
        rrg.grantee,
        rrg.routine_catalog,
        rrg.routine_schema,
        rrg.routine_name,
        fcn.routine_type,
        rrg.privilege_type,
        rrg.is_grantable,
        null::text AS with_hierarchy
    FROM information_schema.role_routine_grants rrg
    LEFT JOIN information_schema.routines fcn
        ON ( fcn.routine_catalog = rrg.routine_catalog
            AND fcn.routine_schema = rrg.routine_schema
            AND fcn.routine_name = rrg.routine_name )
    WHERE rrg.specific_schema NOT IN ( 'pg_catalog', 'information_schema' )
        AND grantor <> grantee
UNION
SELECT rug.grantor,
        rug.grantee,
        rug.udt_catalog,
        rug.udt_schema,
        rug.udt_name,
        ''::text AS udt_type,
        rug.privilege_type,
        rug.is_grantable,
        null::text AS with_hierarchy
    FROM information_schema.role_udt_grants rug
    WHERE rug.udt_schema NOT IN ( 'pg_catalog', 'information_schema' )
        AND substr ( rug.udt_schema, 1, 3 ) <> 'pg_'
        AND grantor <> grantee ;
```

**Updated 2023-01-26** to add an updated query that uses the pg catalog tables instead of the information_schema views. This updated query also contains column grants and function/procedure signatures.

**Updated 2024-03-15** Replaced pg_authid with pg_roles (per Eric Jensen).

```
WITH rol AS (
    SELECT oid,
            rolname::text AS role_name
        FROM pg_roles
    UNION
    SELECT 0::oid AS oid,
            'public'::text
),
schemas AS ( -- Schemas
    SELECT oid AS schema_oid,
            n.nspname::text AS schema_name,
            n.nspowner AS owner_oid,
            'schema'::text AS object_type,
            coalesce ( n.nspacl, acldefault ( 'n'::"char", n.nspowner ) ) AS acl
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
        WHERE n.nspname !~ '^pg_'
            AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
),
classes AS ( -- Tables, views, etc.
    SELECT schemas.schema_oid,
            schemas.schema_name AS object_schema,
            c.oid,
            c.relname::text AS object_name,
            c.relowner AS owner_oid,
            CASE
                WHEN c.relkind = 'r' THEN 'table'
                WHEN c.relkind = 'v' THEN 'view'
                WHEN c.relkind = 'm' THEN 'materialized view'
                WHEN c.relkind = 'c' THEN 'type'
                WHEN c.relkind = 'i' THEN 'index'
                WHEN c.relkind = 'S' THEN 'sequence'
                WHEN c.relkind = 's' THEN 'special'
                WHEN c.relkind = 't' THEN 'TOAST table'
                WHEN c.relkind = 'f' THEN 'foreign table'
                WHEN c.relkind = 'p' THEN 'partitioned table'
                WHEN c.relkind = 'I' THEN 'partitioned index'
                ELSE c.relkind::text
                END AS object_type,
            CASE
                WHEN c.relkind = 'S' THEN coalesce ( c.relacl, acldefault ( 's'::"char", c.relowner ) )
                ELSE coalesce ( c.relacl, acldefault ( 'r'::"char", c.relowner ) )
                END AS acl
        FROM pg_class c
        JOIN schemas
            ON ( schemas.schema_oid = c.relnamespace )
        WHERE c.relkind IN ( 'r', 'v', 'm', 'S', 'f', 'p' )
),
cols AS ( -- Columns
    SELECT c.object_schema,
            null::integer AS oid,
            c.object_name || '.' || a.attname::text AS object_name,
            'column' AS object_type,
            c.owner_oid,
            coalesce ( a.attacl, acldefault ( 'c'::"char", c.owner_oid ) ) AS acl
        FROM pg_attribute a
        JOIN classes c
            ON ( a.attrelid = c.oid )
        WHERE a.attnum > 0
            AND NOT a.attisdropped
),
procs AS ( -- Procedures and functions
    SELECT schemas.schema_oid,
            schemas.schema_name AS object_schema,
            p.oid,
            p.proname::text AS object_name,
            p.proowner AS owner_oid,
            CASE p.prokind
                WHEN 'a' THEN 'aggregate'
                WHEN 'w' THEN 'window'
                WHEN 'p' THEN 'procedure'
                ELSE 'function'
                END AS object_type,
            pg_catalog.pg_get_function_arguments ( p.oid ) AS calling_arguments,
            coalesce ( p.proacl, acldefault ( 'f'::"char", p.proowner ) ) AS acl
        FROM pg_proc p
        JOIN schemas
            ON ( schemas.schema_oid = p.pronamespace )
),
udts AS ( -- User defined types
    SELECT schemas.schema_oid,
            schemas.schema_name AS object_schema,
            t.oid,
            t.typname::text AS object_name,
            t.typowner AS owner_oid,
            CASE t.typtype
                WHEN 'b' THEN 'base type'
                WHEN 'c' THEN 'composite type'
                WHEN 'd' THEN 'domain'
                WHEN 'e' THEN 'enum type'
                WHEN 't' THEN 'pseudo-type'
                WHEN 'r' THEN 'range type'
                WHEN 'm' THEN 'multirange'
                ELSE t.typtype::text
                END AS object_type,
            coalesce ( t.typacl, acldefault ( 'T'::"char", t.typowner ) ) AS acl
        FROM pg_type t
        JOIN schemas
            ON ( schemas.schema_oid = t.typnamespace )
        WHERE ( t.typrelid = 0
                OR ( SELECT c.relkind = 'c'
                        FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
                        WHERE c.oid = t.typrelid ) )
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                    FROM pg_catalog.pg_type el
                    WHERE el.oid = t.typelem
                        AND el.typarray = t.oid )
),
fdws AS ( -- Foreign data wrappers
    SELECT null::oid AS schema_oid,
            null::text AS object_schema,
            p.oid,
            p.fdwname::text AS object_name,
            p.fdwowner AS owner_oid,
            'foreign data wrapper' AS object_type,
            coalesce ( p.fdwacl, acldefault ( 'F'::"char", p.fdwowner ) ) AS acl
        FROM pg_foreign_data_wrapper p
),
fsrvs AS ( -- Foreign servers
    SELECT null::oid AS schema_oid,
            null::text AS object_schema,
            p.oid,
            p.srvname::text AS object_name,
            p.srvowner AS owner_oid,
            'foreign server' AS object_type,
            coalesce ( p.srvacl, acldefault ( 'S'::"char", p.srvowner ) ) AS acl
        FROM pg_foreign_server p
),
all_objects AS (
    SELECT schema_name AS object_schema,
            object_type,
            schema_name AS object_name,
            null::text AS calling_arguments,
            owner_oid,
            acl
        FROM schemas
    UNION
    SELECT object_schema,
            object_type,
            object_name,
            null::text AS calling_arguments,
            owner_oid,
            acl
        FROM classes
    UNION
    SELECT object_schema,
            object_type,
            object_name,
            null::text AS calling_arguments,
            owner_oid,
            acl
        FROM cols
    UNION
    SELECT object_schema,
            object_type,
            object_name,
            calling_arguments,
            owner_oid,
            acl
        FROM procs
    UNION
    SELECT object_schema,
            object_type,
            object_name,
            null::text AS calling_arguments,
            owner_oid,
            acl
        FROM udts
    UNION
    SELECT object_schema,
            object_type,
            object_name,
            null::text AS calling_arguments,
            owner_oid,
            acl
        FROM fdws
    UNION
    SELECT object_schema,
            object_type,
            object_name,
            null::text AS calling_arguments,
            owner_oid,
            acl
        FROM fsrvs
),
acl_base AS (
    SELECT object_schema,
            object_type,
            object_name,
            calling_arguments,
            owner_oid,
            ( aclexplode ( acl ) ).grantor AS grantor_oid,
            ( aclexplode ( acl ) ).grantee AS grantee_oid,
            ( aclexplode ( acl ) ).privilege_type AS privilege_type,
            ( aclexplode ( acl ) ).is_grantable AS is_grantable
        FROM all_objects
)
SELECT acl_base.object_schema,
        acl_base.object_type,
        acl_base.object_name,
        acl_base.calling_arguments,
        owner.role_name AS object_owner,
        grantor.role_name AS grantor,
        grantee.role_name AS grantee,
        acl_base.privilege_type,
        acl_base.is_grantable
    FROM acl_base
    JOIN rol owner
        ON ( owner.oid = acl_base.owner_oid )
    JOIN rol grantor
        ON ( grantor.oid = acl_base.grantor_oid )
    JOIN rol grantee
        ON ( grantee.oid = acl_base.grantee_oid )
    WHERE acl_base.grantor_oid <> acl_base.grantee_oid ;
```

Comment: Thanks man. This statement `GRANT SELECT(id) ON users TO anonymous;`  apparently does not appear in the result.

Comment: I didn't include the column privs. Those can be obtained from the information_schema.role_column_grants view.

Comment: `ERROR:  permission denied for table pg_authid`. This happened on AWS RDS under `postgres` user.

Comment: pg_authid is only superuser you can fix with first statement:
```
WITH rol AS (
    SELECT oid,
            rolname AS role_name
        FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = current_user
    UNION
    SELECT 0::oid AS oid,
            'public'::text
),

and last to:

SELECT acl_base.object_schema,
        acl_base.object_type,
        acl_base.object_name,
        acl_base.calling_arguments,
        grantee.role_name AS grantee,
        acl_base.privilege_type,
        acl_base.is_grantable
    FROM acl_base
    JOIN rol grantee
        ON ( grantee.oid = acl_base.grantee_oid )

Answer (score 3):

There is no simple way to do that in PostgreSQL. You'd have to examine all objects individually. [The access privilege inquiry functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-ACCESS) can help with that.

For example, to list the privileges the current user has on all tables, you could run

```
SELECT t.oid::regclass AS table_name,
       p.name AS privilege
FROM pg_class AS t
   JOIN (VALUES ('SELECT'), ('INSERT'), ('UPDATE'), ('DELETE'),
                ('TRUNCATE'), ('REFERENCES'), ('TRIGGER')) AS p(name)
      ON has_table_privilege(t.oid, p.name)
WHERE t.relkind = 'r';
```

Comment: @EugenKonkov I have added an example.

Comment: Thanks. I checked it works. The query results misses the role to which the given permission was granted.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick check with psql just use:

```
\df+ schema.procedure
```

As usual you can use wildcards.

Answer (score -1):

This query answer to my same question : how to know acl on function ? Hope it can help.

```
SELECT
    routine_catalog AS fct_db,
    routine_schema  AS fct_sch,
    routine_name    AS fct_nam,
    privilege_type  AS fct_priv,
    array_agg (grantee::text ORDER BY grantee::text) AS fct_rol
FROM
    information_schema.routine_privileges
WHERE
    routine_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','pg_catalog')
GROUP BY
    routine_catalog, routine_schema, routine_name, privilege_type
ORDER BY
    routine_catalog, routine_schema, routine_name, privilege_type
;
```

But not working well if a function have same name with differents parameters. For example `dblink (text), dblink (text, boolean), dblink (text, text)`.
For your function, you have to replace `routine_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','pg_catalog')` by `routine_name = 'your_function_name'`