# How to query username, its roles and its roles privileges?

Tags: postgresql

I have tried to query the user, the roles that it has and the privileges that the roles that it has have. I have managed to query the user and roles that it has with the following select:

```
SELECT pg_user.usename, pg_roles.rolname
FROM pg_user
JOIN pg_auth_members ON pg_user.usesysid = pg_auth_members.member
JOIN pg_roles ON pg_roles.oid = pg_auth_members.roleid;
```

But I still would like to query the privileges of the roles of the users. I think I should join the table `role_table_grants` and select its column `privilege_type`, but I have not been able to output what I would like. It gave me zero rows as output.

Does anyone know how I could do it?

Comment: Does this (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/285591/how-to-list-all-grants-per-user-role-on-postgresql/285632#285632) help?

Comment: Not really. Interestingly, it returns different users from when I try to select only users and roles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT r.rolname as member, b.rolname as role, g.table_name, g.privilege_type
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
            JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON m.roleid = b.oid
            JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles r ON m.member = r.oid
            JOIN information_schema.role_table_grants g on b.rolname = g.grantee;
```

Comment: Hi, I tried something similar to it and it outputs no rows. I do not understand well why it happens.