# unable to drop user in PostgreSQL 12.4

Tags: postgresql, permissions, role

I am unable to drop user as I am getting default privileges error.

```
postgres=# drop user xyz;
ERROR: role "xyz" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL: owner of default privileges on new functions belonging to role xyz
```

then I checked default privileges in database,

```
 postgres=# \ddp
Default access privileges
Owner | Schema | Type     | Access privileges
---- -+------- +----------+-------
xyz   |        | function |
```

Could you please let me know how to revoke this default privileges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to grant the “default” default privileges:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE xyz GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO PUBLIC;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE xyz GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO xyz;
```

Then you should be able to drop the role.

Answer (score 1):

This is the safe sequence of commands to drop a role:

Run in every involved database of the DB cluster.

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY xyz TO postgres;
DROP OWNED BY xyz;
```

`DROP OWNED` also gets rid of all privileges and default privileges!

Finally:

```
DROP ROLE xyz;
```

More detailed explanation:

- [Find objects linked to a PostgreSQL role](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155332/find-objects-linked-to-a-postgresql-role/155356#155356)