# Unable to drop user due to assigned privileges?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, users, logins

How do you drop a user with read-only permission to PostgreSQL?

I created a user, with read-only access to all tables, on an RDS Postgres database with:

```
CREATE ROLE myuser WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'supersecretpassword';
ALTER USER myuser SET search_path=myschema;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO myuser;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA myschema TO myuser;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA myschema TO myuser;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO myuser;
```

Now I'd like to drop this user's access, so I tried the obvious:

```
DROP USER myuser;
```

But this gives me the error:

> Could not drop the role.
> ERROR: privileges for database mydb
> privileges for schema myschema
> privileges for default privileges on new relations belonging to role mainrole in schema myschema role "myuser" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it

If I try:

```
DROP OWNED BY myuser;
```

That also gives me the error:

> ERROR:  permission denied to drop objects

My role is the root login for my RDS instance, so not sure why I can't drop objects. Must be some RDS limitation. So maybe if I get a list of all the objects owned by the user I want to drop as outlined in [this post](https://www.dbrnd.com/2018/09/postgresql-script-to-find-all-objects-of-a-particular-user/), I can get a sense of what I need to reassign?

However, if I run:

```
select 
    nsp.nspname as SchemaName
    ,cls.relname as ObjectName 
    ,rol.rolname as ObjectOwner
    ,case cls.relkind
        when 'r' then 'TABLE'
        when 'm' then 'MATERIALIZED_VIEW'
        when 'i' then 'INDEX'
        when 'S' then 'SEQUENCE'
        when 'v' then 'VIEW'
        when 'c' then 'TYPE'
        else cls.relkind::text
    end as ObjectType
from pg_class cls
join pg_roles rol 
    on rol.oid = cls.relowner
join pg_namespace nsp 
    on nsp.oid = cls.relnamespace
where nsp.nspname not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
    and nsp.nspname not like 'pg_toast%'
    and rol.rolname = 'myuser'  
order by nsp.nspname, cls.relname
```

it returns nothing.

So I can't drop the user because it owns stuff. But also it doesn't own anything? What am I missing?

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840955/postgresql-drop-role-fails-because-of-default-privileges) but none of its solution work, presumably because this is on RDS.

Answer (score 2):

This is the **safe sequence of commands**:

**Repeat in every database** of the same DB cluster, where the role may own anything or may have any privileges:

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY myuser TO rds_superuser;  -- optional; see below
DROP OWNED BY myuser;
```

**Then, once**, in any database of the same DB cluster:

```
DROP ROLE myuser;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropuser.html)

> `DROP USER` is simply an alternate spelling of `DROP ROLE`.

[`DROP OWNED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-drop-owned.html) **also** removes all privileges **including** `DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`, which is your problem in particular.

[`REASSIGN OWNED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reassign-owned.html) is optional in your case, since the role `myuser` does not own anything (but privileges). But it's the safe way if there can be objects that you might not want to destroy. I chose `rds_superuser` as target role sionce that seems to be the role you are operating with. Adjust to your needs. The manual:

> `REASSIGN OWNED` requires membership on both the source role(s) and the target role.

See:

- [Cannot drop PostgreSQL role. Error: `cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51257346/939860)
- [Find objects linked to a PostgreSQL role](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155332/find-objects-linked-to-a-postgresql-role/155356#155356)

Comment: Like I mentioned, the solutions in that other question do not work for me. Specifically, RDS does not support "REASSIGN" and gives me the error `ERROR:  permission denied to reassign objects` even for my RDS superuser.

Comment: Like I said, `REASSIGN OWNED` is optional for you. `DROP OWNED` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you first need to drop default privileges you granted:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema REVOKE SELECT ON TABLES FROM myuser;
```

You can get default privileges using the query from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14555063

```
 SELECT 
  nspname,         -- schema name
  defaclobjtype,   -- object type
  defaclacl        -- default access privileges
FROM pg_default_acl a JOIN pg_namespace b ON a.defaclnamespace=b.oid;
```

Comment: Even after revoking those privileges, running `DROP USER myuser;` still results in: `ERROR:  role "myuser" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  privileges for database mydb
privileges for schema myschema`

Comment: If you tried `DROP OWNED` (which should take care of permissions) and it gave you an 
error , I'd suggest trying revoking everything you granted explicitly in addition to revoking default privileges. E.g. `REVOKE USAGE` ,`REVOKE CONNECT` , `REVOKE SELECT` and then try to drop user again.