# Show all privileges given to a schema or user in postgres

Tags: postgresql, permissions, query

I want to know what are the privileges a given schema or user has in Postgres. Like whether it can create a table, view, function, sequences or not.

I found one query but it showed privileges on table only. Please suggest any appropriate query.

Comment: [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/184339/72070) may help you if you use `psql`.

Comment: That was useful for knowing previleges on table by a user . But how to know whether a user have permission to create a sequence, views and function ? One obvious way is to try creating them and check . But I don't have write permission to do that .

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL, the right to create tables, views, functions, operators, data types and the like is not properties of the user (or “role” in PostgreSQL).

You manage this with privileges on schemas: if there is a schema where the user has the `CREATE` privilege, the user can create any object he or she wishes in that schema. If you want to keep a PostgreSQL user from creating objects, you don't give them `CREATE` on any schema. Since the `public` schema by default gives `CREATE` to everybody, you'd have to

```
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
```

which is a good idea anyway for security reasons.

There are only few privileges that are tied to the user, because they pertain to global objects or no objects at all:

- `CREATEDB`: the right to run `CREATE DATABASE`
- `CREATEROLES`: the right to run `CREATE ROLE`
- `REPLICATION`: the right to establish a replication connection; that is for example needed for `pg_basebackup`

Comment: "* is not attached to the user*" - hmm, as you grant the `create`  privilege on a schema **to** a user (or role), I would say it is (somehow)  "tied" to a user (the grantee).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was thinking literally: the privileges are ACL settings on objects, not properties of the user. I'll try to pick a better way to say it.

Comment: Yes , you guessed it correctly, I am a oracle user but now learning postgres as well . We are migrating the data from oracle to postgres . So faced some issue with grants after migrating oracle data to postgres . So, do we have any query or psql command for knowing that whether a user has rights to create a sequence or not ? Or in postgres there is no such grants for sequence exist .

Comment: That would be `\dn+` in `psql`. Then you see which of the schemas the user has the `CREATE` permission on.