# Get all possible privilege kinds for different object types

Tags: postgresql

I need to get all possible privilege kinds for all types of objects, e.g.

| TYPE | KINDS |
| --- | --- |
| TABLE | {SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE...} |
| SCHEMA | {CREATE, USAGE} |
| ... | ... |

I need not specific grants on object or role, but possible grants like [image]

In the end, I need to check if a role has ALL grants on an object. E.g. [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/152566/245663) says how to find which grants the grantee has, but I don't know how to check if there are no more other grants.

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Could you possible be a bit more specific? Are you searching for a list of possible privileges/permissions that PostgreSQL provides? Or are you looking for a script that will retrieve the privileges/permissions for a specific PostgreSQL user/role? Please [edit] your question and provide more details and possibly an example. Thank you. With your support, the community should be able to provide you with a solution.

Comment: @JohnK.N. I need all possible. added some more info to the question

Comment: @AlexTonkonozhenko just check if it has the "ALL" privilege.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille how can I do it? I see many privileges granted, but not `ALL` permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a user for the sole purpose of this exercise:

```
create user ulysses@'%' identified by 'HariM';
```

Grant all privileges on an object of the type you wish to investigate, eg. a table.

```
grant all on ghp.test to ulysses;
```

Now you can query the mysql.tables_priv, the table_priv column contains a comma separated list of all possible privileges. A user or role that doesn't have the same values, doesn't have all privileges on that type of object.

```
MariaDB [ghp]> select table_priv from mysql.tables_priv where user = 'ulysses' and db = 'ghp' and table_name = 'test';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| table_priv                                                                                                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Select,Insert,Update,Delete,Create,Drop,References,Index,Alter,Create View,Show view,Trigger,Delete versioning rows |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: Look like it's the only solution. Thanks!