# How do I see which roles have `admin option` on them?

Tags: postgresql, role

I've seen plenty of questions about someone trying to grant a *role_specification* to some *other_role*, but getting the `GRANT` error

`ERROR:  must have admin option on role`***`role_specification`***

and the answers all in some way or other seem to boil down to "That's happening because the `WITH ADMIN` wasn't used when the original `GRANT`***`role`***`TO`***`role_specification`***`...`  was issued."

So now, I can't do  `GRANT`*`role_specification`*`TO`*`other_role`*

But what has stumped me is that I can't find anything about how to actually *see* if the admin option is set for a role.  Answers like [List the database privileges using psql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/4286/80826) reveal privileges for roles, but none of those attributes appear to correspond to be corresponding to the `admin option`.  The Postgres documentation seems mute on this, too.

So... where does Postgres keep track of this, and how can I query for it?

---

Based on the answer by @Erwin Brandstetter I have a few deeper questions...

- \drg is not availble to me.  I take it that's in a version of Postgres newer than 13?
- That makes the SQL really valuable, but I'm not sure how that translates.  My result is:

```
SELECT roleid::regrole, member::regrole, grantor::regrole, admin_option
FROM   pg_auth_members where roleid::regrole::text like 'content%';;
    roleid     |    member     |    grantor    | admin_option 
---------------+---------------+---------------+--------------
 content_adm   | int_web_admin | content_adm   | f
 content_rwd   | randall       | postgres      | f
 content_rwd   | content_adm   | postgres      | f
```

All of the `roleid`s have the `admin_option` as false in all of the rows of the pg_auth_members table (but a `postgres` roleid was notably *not* there).  Even so, content_adm can grant content_adm  to the int_web_admin role, but it cannot grant content_rwd to it.

The relevant lines of `\du` show:

```
    Role name     |  Attributes    |            Member of             
------------------+----------------+----------------------------------
 content_adm      |                | {content_rwd}
 content_rwd      | Cannot login   | {}
 randall          |                | {content_rwd}
 int_web_admin    |                | {sys_role,content_adm}
```

(I believe the *content_adm* and *randall* membership of *content_rwd* was set up by the previous DBA)

So my second follow-up question is: How do I translate the SQL query result to information similar to the `\drg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The admin option is set for a membership of a role in another role (a.k.a. "group role"). So it's not an attribute of the role itself.

Information about memberships is stored in the system catalog [`pg_auth_members`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-auth-members.html) - in a single instance for the whole DB cluster.

So which roles have the "admin option" in which group - granted by whom?

```
SELECT roleid::regrole, member::regrole, grantor::regrole, admin_option
FROM   pg_auth_members;
```

In **Postgres 16**, a corresponding [meta-command has been added to psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-DRG): **`\drg`**:

```
test=> \drg
                  List of role grants
 Role name | Member of |       Options       | Grantor  
-----------+-----------+---------------------+----------
 erwin     | dummy     | INHERIT, SET        | postgres
 erwin     | postgres  | ADMIN, INHERIT, SET | postgres
(2 rows)
```

Or `\drgS` to also include system roles.

I granted the admin option in role `postgres` to `erwin` to demonstrate. The superuser "postgres" has no members by default. But if you make a role member (an extremely empowering move), that role can do anything after `SET role postgres`, regardless of the admin option

To get the same result in **any modern version** with plain SQL:

```
SELECT m.rolname AS "Role name"
     , roleid::regrole AS "Member of"
     , pg_catalog.concat_ws(', ', CASE WHEN pam.admin_option THEN 'ADMIN'   END
                                , CASE WHEN m.rolinherit     THEN 'INHERIT' END
                                , 'SET'
                           ) AS "Options"
     , grantor::regrole AS "Grantor"
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_auth_members pam
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_roles m ON pam.member = m.oid
WHERE  m.rolname !~ '^pg_'
ORDER  BY 1, 2, 4;
```

I had a peek at the implementation of `\drg` in Postgres 16, which is equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, @Erwin Brandstetter.   The SELECT statement has different results from \drg (which I can't use), so I've edited my question with the specifics.  Could you take a look and let me know what you think?

Comment: @Randall: See my additions above.